# Can I apply for an H4 visa for my wife if my H1 is approved?

Tags: usa, visa, h1-visa, h4-visa

I am an Indian national on an F1 visa. I am currently working in a startup in San Jose. I applied for an H1B visa under Consular process and my H1B was recently picked and approved (I have an I-797B).

Can I apply for an H4 visa for my wife or do I have to wait for the visa to be stamped on my passport? Please note that I am still on F1 even though my H4 was approved as I applied my H1 under Consular process.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to wait for the H1B to be stamped in your passport before applying for your wife's H4.
Apply now.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a document on USCUS which says so. Any reference?